# PHP - How to echo a code as a text

Tags: php, mysql, database

Now I got a query that contains HTML code and when I select it in php it makes the code,

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table`")or die(mysql_error());
while($arr = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$num = mysql_num_rows($query);
$code = $arr ['code'];
echo $code;
}
```

and in that query there is this code `<a href="http://google.com">Click Here</a>`

when it echo it shows me Click Here, But I want it to sows me the code.

So how can I do that in PHP.

Thanks 
 Klaus

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `htmlspecialchars()` to prevent HTML elements from being interpreted by the browser.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table`")or die(mysql_error());
while($arr = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $num = mysql_num_rows($query);
    $code = $arr ['code'];
    echo htmlspecialchars($code);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just encode the output with `htmlspecialchars`

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table`")or die(mysql_error());
while($arr = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$num = mysql_num_rows($query);
$code = $arr ['code'];
echo htmlspecialchars($code);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/it/function.htmlentities.php):

```
echo htmlentities($code);
```

> This function is identical to htmlspecialchars() in all ways, except
>   with htmlentities(), all characters which have HTML character entity
>   equivalents are translated into these entities.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use:-

```
echo htmlentities($code);
```

The `htmlentities()` function takes a string and returns the same string with HTML converted into HTML entities.

It prevents the browser from using it as an HTML element and it prevents the code from running if you were to display some user's input on your website.